# Changing Date with Radio Buttons in Javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, getdate

So I've gotten my code to display the correct current date in the 1st text box, but then when I choose one of the radio buttons to choose my "Pick-Up" date, the 2nd text box does not display the date.  Basically, 1st box should show current date, 2nd box should show the date chosen from the radio buttons (imagine dropping off film that needs developed and you are choosing whether you want it 1 day, 2 days, or 3 days processing).  I am including my full code so you can see what I'm doing.  Can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong...

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function my_curr_date() {      
var currentDate = new Date()
  var day = currentDate.getDate();
  var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
var my_date = month+"-"+day+"-"+year;
document.getElementById("dateField").value=my_date;

}
function orderReady(orderTime){
dateToday.setDate(dateToday.getDate()+orderTime);
var ready=dateToday.getMonth()+"/"
+dateToday.getDate()+"/"+dateToday.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("duedateField").value=ready;
}
```

```
<p>Item<br />
<input type="radio" name="item" value="print_5x7" onclick="orderReady(1)" />5x7 Prints(1 day)
<input type="radio" name="item" value="poster" onclick="orderReady(1)" />Poster (1 day)
<input type="radio" name="item" value="mug" onclick="orderReady(2)" />Coffee Mug (2 days)
<input type="radio" name="item" value="shirt" onclick="orderReady(3)" />T-shirt (3 days)</p>

<p>Today's Date<br />
<input type='text' name='dateField' id='dateField' value='' /><br />
Pick-up Date<br />
<input type='text' name='duedateField' id='duedateField' value='' /></p>
```

Comment: "due_date"? .WHere is it specified.

Comment: I changed "due_date" to "ready".  I did not specify "due_date", but I did not specify "my_date" in the first function either, but it is working....

Comment: where did u called my_curr_date() ?

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the `duedateField` value to the result you have calculated

i think this

```
function orderReady(orderTime){
dateToday.setDate(dateToday.getDate()+orderTime);
var ready=dateToday.getMonth()+"/"
+dateToday.getDate()+"/"+dateToday.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("duedateField").value=due_date;
}
```

should be

```
function orderReady(orderTime){
dateToday.setDate(dateToday.getDate()+orderTime);
var ready=dateToday.getMonth()+"/"
+dateToday.getDate()+"/"+dateToday.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("duedateField").value=ready;
}
```

you have to set `ready` for the `duedateField` value

Comment: Still does not display the adjusted date.  I know I'm missing something silly, but I just can't see it.  Been staring at this code all day, and starting to go cross-eyed.  Any other help?

Answer (score 0):

it is so simple dude

```
function orderReady(orderTime){
dateToday.setDate(dateToday.getDate()+orderTime);
var ready=dateToday.getMonth()+"/"
+dateToday.getDate()+"/"+dateToday.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("duedateField").value=due_date;
}
```

you should replace `value=due_date` with `value=ready`

Comment: I did that, but have no change in my result.  I'm so confused as to why this isn't working.  I know it's something stupid, but I've been looking at this code all day and think I just need another set of eyes to look the code over.

Comment: then what it exactly giving the output?

Comment: There should be a resulting date that is 1-3 days later than the current date.  But right now, clicking any of the radio buttons does nothing at all.  No date populates the 2nd text box.

Comment: ok now i got it.... you made two function so to get result first you have to call them. i mean put onClick="my_curr_date()" in your input boxes. now when you will click in input box then it will show you date. but unfortunately i didn't find any way that it can show date without clicking on it. yeaah but it is possible if you use button with it and call the function through button. i hope it will help you :)